# Need to calculate value in each loop and sum together in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, sum, accumulate

Say I have a simple input XML document like:

```
<Amounts>
    <item>
        <Base>4750</Base>
        <Tax1>2800</Tax1>
        <Tax2>50</Tax2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Base>4750</Base>
        <Tax1>2800</Tax1>
        <Tax2>50</Tax2>
    </item>
</Amounts>
```

And an XSLT as:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output  version="1.0" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:element name="MyTax">
        <xsl:variable name="bf" select="sum(//item/Base)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="discount" select="$bf * 0.08"/>
        <xsl:variable name="bf1" select="$bf - $discount"/>
        <xsl:variable name="yq1" select="sum(//item/Tax1)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="yr1" select="sum(//item/Tax2)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="stax">
            <xsl:value-of select="round(format-number((($bf1 + $yq1 + $yr1) * 0.0495),'#.##'))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:element name="Stax"><xsl:value-of select="$stax"/></xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

We get an output XML as:

```
<MyTax>
    <Stax>715</Stax>
</MyTax>
```

However, now i'd like to compute stax separately for each item and then sum those items up - this is because in the above example I end up with rounding errors as the sum of the individual stax is actually 714 - the value I am looking for, rather than 715 above.

So the output I am looking for would be:

```
<MyTax>
         <item>
    <Stax>357</Stax>
         </item>
         <item>
            <Stax>357</Stax>
         </item>
         <TotalStax>714</TotalStax>
</MyTax>
```

Though I can set up a for-each, how do I compute stax into a variable for each pass, and then sum up the individual stax? I am limited XSLT 1.0, saw some answers using keys and nodesets but am not able to understand how to apply them.

Comment: Your XSLT only does one stax calculation over the entire input.  It cannot produce the output you show.  The calculated value of `stax` is 714.78, which you've asked the processor to round.  This rounds to 715.  Why do you want 714 output?

Comment: Jim, I'm actually needing to produce the 714 sum - that comes only by calculating the stax separately in each run (357) and summing all the individual stax - giving me 357+357 = 714 instead of the 715 if I do the computation on the sum of the individual items. I am unable to create the XSLT for this required output...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This XSLT 1.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <xsl:variable name="vrtfTaxSeq">
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:value-of select="sum(ext:node-set($vrtfTaxSeq)/*)"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="item">
  <ttax>
   <xsl:value-of select="round(0.0495*(Base - 0.08*Base + Tax1 + Tax2))"/>
  </ttax>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Amounts>
    <item>
        <Base>4750</Base>
        <Tax1>2800</Tax1>
        <Tax2>50</Tax2>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Base>4750</Base>
        <Tax1>2800</Tax1>
        <Tax2>50</Tax2>
    </item>
</Amounts>
```

**calculates the sums for each `item` and produces the wanted result**:

```
714
```

**Do note** that the `xxx:node-set()` extension function is necessary (this can be avoided using recursion).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This does produce the correct result for the above data, but I was curious why you used floor (and why it works?) when I need to do round as per our requirement on the resulting calculation and then sum up - I need to also be able to round up if the answer results in such a value.

Comment: @Surge, There is no way to get 714 -- the actual result is > 714.5

Comment: What I was trying to get to was round(4750 - 4750*0.08 + 2800 + 50) = round(357.39) = 357 for each item above, and then sum (357, 357) = 714. Rather than what I had previously been doing as round(0.0495*(8740+5600+100)) = round(714.78) = 715 which was incorrect for my application. In addition the discount is a param so instead of 0.08 (8% discount), I could have 12% yielding round(0.0495*(4750*0.88+2800+50)) = 348. And summing up to 348+348 = 696. In your xsl the value would floor and instead become 695, while I need 696. How do I round at each item, and then sum each result?

Comment: You need to edit your question and explain this requirement -- forcing people to guess results in unwanted answers.

Comment: Sorry I didnt notice I had unchecked the accept. I was trying to vote it as useful. @Dimitre, your answer provides me ample direction towards a solution, so it is surely helpful. I thought I'd clarified in the beginning what i'm trying to put out by way of the desired output XML as two sets of Stax for the items and finally the TotalStax which would be the simple sum of the individual Stax. The example XSL I provided was for what I was currently doing, i.e. adding everything and then computing the round(0.0495*....) , while stating what i'd like to get.

Comment: @Surge, Now that I know from your *comment* that you want to apply `round()` separately for each `item`, I'll try to come up with a solution for this new problem.