# Count the number of elements which match a certain criteria using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I need to count the number of students who have failed an exam or those with some wrong data. This `if loop` condition is working properly, but the count of the number of students is wrong.

```
<xsl:if test ="$StudentFinalmark &gt; 100 or $StudentFinalmark &lt; 49">
    <xsl:value-of select = "count(StudentFinalmark)"/>            
</xsl:if>
```

For example, if there are four failed students and students with two wrong dates, it's coming as **111111**

Please help me with the solution.

Comment: <xsl:if test ="$StudentFinalmark &gt; 100 or $StudentFinalmark &lt; 49">
                               <xsl:value-of select = "count(StudentFinalmark)"/>

                        </xsl:if>

Comment: Please [edit] your question with a meaningful title and include your code instead of posting as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your xml looked like this (as per your comment below):

```
<Students>
    <StudentResults>
        <Marks>
            <StudentAssign1>40</StudentAssign1>
            <StudentAssign2>40</StudentAssign2>
            <StudentExam>40</StudentExam>
        </Marks>
    </StudentResults>
    <StudentResults>
        <Marks>
            <StudentAssign1>1</StudentAssign1>
            <StudentAssign2>2</StudentAssign2>
            <StudentExam>3</StudentExam>
        </Marks>
    </StudentResults>
    <StudentResults>
        <Marks>
            <StudentAssign1>33</StudentAssign1>
            <StudentAssign2>33</StudentAssign2>
            <StudentExam>33</StudentExam>
        </Marks>
    </StudentResults>
</Students>
```

an XSLT like this will return the results you are after:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="Output">
            <xsl:value-of select="count(Students/StudentResults[sum(Marks/*) &gt; 100 or sum(Marks/*) &lt; 49])" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This returns the result:

```
<Output>2</Output>
```

It returns two because, in the example XML above, the first StudentResults has a sum of 120 (which fails because it is bigger than 100) and the second has a sum of 6 (which fails because it is less than 49)

The trick is to output a single item which is a count of the elements which you select via xpath, not via an "if" and "for" combination.  There isn't a need to use a variable either.

Comment: Hi I tried this. It's not working. Actually StudentFinalmark is a local variable in my XSLT. Shall I send you my whole XSLT code. very urgent. please help...

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="StudentResults">
                  <xsl:variable name="StudentFinalmark">
                         <xsl:value-of select= "sum((Marks/StudentAssign1 | Marks/StudentAssign2 | Marks/StudentExam)[number(.) = .])"/>
                   </xsl:variable>
                   <xsl:if test ="$StudentFinalmark &gt; 100 or $StudentFinalmark &lt; 49">
                                 <xsl:value-of select = "count(StudentFinalmark)"/>            
                     </xsl:if>
                     
              </xsl:for-each>

Comment: Many Many  thanks GHC. For one week I am struggling with it.

Comment: @Lavanya No worries.  If your conditions were more complex, you could always use variables and a node-set (although not core XSLT) see: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148780/need-to-calculate-value-in-each-loop-and-sum-together-in-xslt-1-0.  If you've got everything you need here, can you mark the answer as accepted?